# How to add previous time spent and recent time spent on the same level?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I add the previous time the player spent playing for example level 1 and the next time he played the same level will be added to the previous time, which will be shown on the result board.

For getting the time in seconds we used

```
timereasy1 += Time.deltaTime;
```

and then saving it to

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("timer1",timereasy1);
```

and adding it to

```
totaltime=totaltime+timer1;
```

but it won't add up... It will still show the recent time spent of the player.

Comment: You should add a bit code

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the value like you are but you can simplify it like so.

```
private float _timePlayed;

private void Awake()
{
    //When the Game/Level starts get the previous amount of time played if there is a PlayerPref for it otherwise it defaults to 0 as an unset float
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("timer1"))
    {
        _timePlayed = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("timer1");
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    //Update the Time played during Game Play 
    _timePlayed += Time.deltaTime;
}

private void GameOver()
{
    //At the end of the Game/Level update the PlayerPref with the new value
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("timer1", _timePlayed);
}
```